# Reading XML with Excel VBA

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I'm trying to essentially obtain the "Rate" value in the below XML using VBA (this is a much shortened version, the actual has over 500 rates to choose from). I'm struggling to get to it without having to cycle through every single node till I reach the right one.

```
-<DC>
- <Overviews>
      - <OverviewCurve>
         <Identifier>zero_libor_usd</Identifier>
         - <Curve>
           - <YieldCurve>
               - <Node>
                   <Term>32</Term> 
                   <Rate>0.027613082673910938</Rate> 
                 </Node>
            </YieldCurve>
          </Curve>
       </OverviewCurve>
 </Overviews>
</DC>
```

The code I am attempting to use is..

```
Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.Load (Range("Path").Value & Range("FileName").Value)
Set xmlNode2 =xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/DC/Overviews/OverviewCurve/Identifier/Curve/YieldCurve/Node/Rate")
```

But the code returns "Nothing" for xmlNode2. The xml file itself essentially has 5 other "OverviewCurve" nodes all structured in the same way with 50 "rate" nodes (ie 50 "term" nodes). I'm trying to obtain each of these from the file. I've removed some other nodes that are child to the "Overviews" node as they are not relevant for what I am trying to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple `Rate` nodes, then the `XPATH` "/DC/Overviews/OverviewCurve/Identifier/Curve/YieldCurve/Node/Rate" will not be a `SingleNode`.

Example

```
 Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
 Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
 Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

 Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
 xmlDoc.async = False
 xmlDoc.Load "P:\test.xml"

 Set xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Rate[1]") 'xmlNode is now the first Rate

 Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Rate") 'xmlNodeList is now a list of all Rate nodes
```

The syntax is `XPATH` see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath.